Drag and Drop table rows from one table to another
I am trying to implement a drag and drop function in my razor page. The razor page looks like this:
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@inject TestApi2 testApi2
@inject TestApi testApi

<PageTitle>Test</PageTitle>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        Teststellung
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="column">
                <table id="table2" @ondrop="OnDrop" @ondragover="AllowDrop">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nr</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @if (droppedClass.Count() == 0)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
                            {
                                <tr class="red-row">
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (var class in droppedClass)
                            {
                                <tr class="red-row">
                                    <td>@class.Nr</td>
                                    <td>@class.Name</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="test-plan-table">
                    <table id="table1">
                        <thead>
                             <tr>
                                <th>Nr</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <!-- Example red rows -->
                            @foreach (var class in draggedClass)
                            {
                                <tr class="red-row list-item" @ondragstart="@((e) => OnDragStart(e, test))" draggable="true">
                                    <td>@class.Nr</td>
                                    <td>@class.Name</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private ICollection<Class1> draggedClass = new List<Class1>();
    private ICollection<Class1> droppedClass = new List<Class1>();
    private ICollection<Class2> mainClass = new List<Class2> { };
    public bool isModalVisible;

    private Class1 draggedItem = new Class1();

    // Start dragging
    private void OnDragStart(DragEventArgs e, Class1 item)
    {
        draggedItem = item;
        e.DataTransfer.EffectAllowed = "move";
    }

    // Allow drop on target
    private void AllowDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DataTransfer.DropEffect = "move";
    }

    // Handle drop event
    private void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (draggedItem != null)
        {
            draggedClass.Remove(draggedItem);
            droppedClass.Add(draggedItem);
            draggedItem = null;
            StateHasChanged(); // Trigger UI update
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        mainClass = await testApi2.GetItems();
        draggedClass = await testApi.GetItems();
    }
}

In the example the table row should be draggable from the table with the id "table1" to the table with the id "table2".
I tried this approach, but it won't work. I also tried to make the table row as an additional razor page and then approach it as an dragged object, but didn't work

You need to add a dragover element to make  it work.
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        Teststellung
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="column" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
            <table id="table2" @ondrop="OnDrop" @ondragover="AllowDrop">
                ...
            </table>
        ...
    </div>
</div>


Here is a sample you could refer to https://chrissainty.com/investigating-drag-and-drop-with-blazor/
